# get -2 object with jquery similar to :last-child

Tags: jquery, html

if i have such HTML structure
how can I get -2 item : `<p>C</p>`

```
<div class='m'>
<span><p>A</p></span>
<span><p>B</p></span>
<span><p>C</p></span>
<span><p>D</p></span>
<div>
```

will this work?

```
div.m > span:nth-last-child(2) > p

>> <span><p>C</p></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.eq(index)` selector

```
$(".m span").eq(2).text()
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vtL8xcsy/61/)

Comment: what if :  alert($(".numbers span").eq(-2).text()); ??

Comment: -2 will take -2 element

Answer (score 1):

If you fix your HTML (your closing `<div>` is actually an opening tag), [nth-last-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/) should work fine:

```js
alert($( "div.m > span:nth-last-child(2) > p" ).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='m'>
    <span><p>A</p></span>
    <span><p>B</p></span>
    <span><p>C</p></span>
    <span><p>D</p></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose CSS does not provide backward navigation, So, there is no previous selector for CSS, you can use jQuery `previous()` to get the element in -2 position.

```
$(".m span:last").previous().find('p').css('background-color', 'red');
```

or you can simply do it with jQuery `eq(-2)` like this:

```
$(".m span").eq(-2).find('p').css('background-color', 'red');
```

It work for all cases and gets the element before the last child

```
<div class='m'>
   <span><p>A</p></span>
   <span><p>B</p></span>
   <span><p>C</p></span>
   <span><p>D</p></span>
<div>

<div class='m'>
   <span><p>A</p></span>
   <span><p>B</p></span>
   <span><p>X</p></span>
   <span><p>P</p></span>
   <span><p>C</p></span>
   <span><p>D</p></span>
<div>
```